# Returning nested collection elements as objects in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, cherrypy

I've inserted the following document on my mongo database using Python:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def create(self):
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client.database_name        
    result = db.users.insert_one({
        "email": "email@email.com",
        "company": {
            "name": "ABC Company"
        }
    })
```

Now, I've stored the results from the collection query, using variables (company_name):

```
 @cherrypy.expose
 def result(self):
     client = MongoClient()
     db = client.database_name        
     cursor = db.users.find({"email":"email@email.com"})
     for document in cursor:
        email = document["email"]
        company_name = document["company"]["name"]
     return company_name
```

I would like to return the nested element as object, like: company.name instead as variable (company_name)

How can I modify my result function to store the collection results as object attributes?

1 - I using CherryPy as HTTP server. I'm not using any ORM, nor Template engine.

Comment: You need to create a Python class that describes the object, and return an instance of the class.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to return the whole `{
        "email": "email@email.com",
        "company": {
            "name": "ABC Company"
        }
    }` object from the HTTP handler in JSON format?

Comment: Yes, I want to return the whole object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `namedtuple` from `collections` module:

```
from collections import namedtuple
company = namedtuple('company ', 'name') 
document = namedtuple('document ', 'email, company')
```

and then inside the loop:

```
for row in cursor:
    result = document(row["email"], company(row["company"]["name"]))
    yield result # or 'return result' if there is only one of them
```

`namedtuple` will you access your arguments (but read only since it's a tuple) both as positional (by index [0], [1], etc.) and as attributes (result.email).  All attributes are also read-only properties, so they come with pre-baked `fget` function which can be used in `map` and `filter`.

Comment: Can I pass these as arguments on to other functions using these new notation? for example - def new(result.name)

Comment: Or better, how should I pass these to a file? Following this example: return template.format(result=result) ?

Comment: @Gerr, any instance created with the builder function which you get out of `namedtuple` is, in fact, a tuple and a class instance.  So you can use it as either.  On an unrelated note, I would not use `new` as a name for your own function because it's already used by Python during the process of creating of regular objects.  It can get confusing in debugging, or worse, mess up the process of regular object creation.  Another thing to note is that `namedtuple` is implemented purely in Python (no C), so you can take a look at what it does inside of the `collections` module.